# How to allow other users to register with an email already taken but not confirmed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, registration, devise-confirmable

I'm developing an application that requires authentication with devise/rails and it was decided to allow users sign in without email confirmation. However, after a deep thinking this odd workflow came in mind:

> What if someone registers with my email, starts using it and later
>   I decide to join the app with my stolen email? The guy did not
>   confirm, but should I keep his account, block it or remove it?
>   (side note: email must be unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a very similar problem and the solution I've arrived (not implemented yet) is to make the user choose the email he want if there is not other confirmed user with that e-mail.

Once registered the user will be uncorfimed/nonactive and will receive a confirmation e-mail, when it will follow the link it will confirm his e-mail and other can't use it anymore.

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate your solution but implement it might be a little headache since the user email must be unique

Answer (score 3):

As the designer of the application, you are in control. You can handle that situation how you would like.

I'm not sure how facebook deals with 'unconfirmed' account creations. I would imagine that they allow whoever registered to check their e-mail and click the confirmation link within a certain amount of time - after which that e-mail becomes available for use by other users. This makes sense to me, as this would prevent people from spamming the site and effectively 'e-mail blocking' legitimate users from registering. If you forever allow unconfirmed accounts to sit and 'use up' e-mails, you could run into the following situation:

A malicious user creates thousands of 'fake' account registration attempts with bogus e-mails. These e-mails sit and wait forever to be confirmed, but never will be because they don't exist (yet), acting as 'in-use' e-mails. Some time later, a legit user happens to create an e-mail account with GMail or whoever that happens to match one of the 'bogus' e-mails submitted by the malicious user earlier. This legit user is then unable to register his or her e-mail with your service because the malicious user has 'e-mail blocked' this address.

My personal opinion is to give the registrant a certain amount of time to confirm their address as legitimate, and if they never confirm within that time frame, just discard the account creation attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these sites require you to verify your email by sending you an email link. Only afterwards can you create an account. This handily sidesteps the problem of someone trying to steal someone else's email: unless they can log into your email account, they simply cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 'resend confirmation email' action (you should) or 'password forgotten' action (you should)? With both I could reclaim the account with my email address as only I have access to my emails.

Also think about the case of the user who creates an account, forgets about it and creates another account with the same email address.